# Number of prime number between 1 and n finishing by 1

Tags: c++11

I don't have a lot of experience in C++. Could anyone be able to build a program that counts the number of prime numbers between 1 and n finishing by 1?

Comment: This is one of the most common basic programming exercises. You can find literally hundreds if not thousands of solutions if you google for "c++ count number of primes".

Comment: @Juhana but with the condition to end up by $1$ is a way more complicated.

Comment: Not really. All you have to do is not count the number if it doesn't end in 1. If you don't know how to do that, google for "c++ get last digit of integer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I implement a function which checks whether a number is prime or not.

```
bool isPrime(const unsigned int number) {
  if (number == 0) return false;
  if (number == 1 || number == 2) return true;

  const unsigned int half_number = number / 2;

  for (unsigned int i = 2; i <= half_number; ++i) {
    if (number % i == 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

After you can implement a function which checks whether the last digit is 1:

```
bool lastDigitOne(const unsigned int number) {
  return (number % 10) == 1 ? true : false; 
}
```

Finally the counting code:

```
unsigned int countingCode(const unsigned int N) {
  unsigned int counter = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
    if (isPrime(i) == true && lastDigitOne(i)) {
      ++counter;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```